# C++ Operator Overload spits out garbage values

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

The current output is a garbage 8 digit value. I am not quite sure why the addition function is not adding 1 and 2.
ALSO, how would I implement a function for:

```
TrashCan other = combined – myCan;
cout << "the other cup's filled to " << other.getUsed( ) << endl;
```

Here's the code:

main:

```
int main()

{
cout << "Welcome to Howie's TrashCan Program!" << endl;

TrashCan myCan;
TrashCan yourCan;

yourCan.setSize( 12 );
myCan.setSize( 12 );

yourCan.addItem( );
yourCan.addItem( );
myCan.addItem( );

myCan.printCan();
yourCan.printCan();

TrashCan combined = yourCan + myCan;
cout << "this drive's filled to " << combined.getUsed( ) << endl;...
```

Class:

```
class TrashCan {
public:
TrashCan( );
TrashCan( int size );
TrashCan( int size, int contents );
TrashCan operator+(TrashCan);
TrashCan operator-(TrashCan);
void setSize( int size );
void addItem( );
void empty( );
void cover( );
void uncover( );

void printCan( );
int getUsed();

private:
bool myIsCovered;
int my_Size;
int my_Contents;
};
```

implementation: (I'm assuming that I messed up on one of the following functions)

```
TrashCan TrashCan::operator+ (TrashCan A)
{
TrashCan combined;
combined.my_Contents= my_Contents + A.my_Contents;
}

int TrashCan::getUsed()
{
return my_Contents;
}
```

Comment: Turn up your warning level.

Answer (score 1):

You don't return the temporary in your function:

```
TrashCan TrashCan::operator+ (TrashCan A)
{
TrashCan combined;
combined.my_Contents= my_Contents + A.my_Contents;
// should be
return combined;
}
```

Comment: Also, how would I implement the subtraction function I had edited into my main?

Comment: @user2924131 Exactly the same way. I suspect you need to do more in your operators when setting up the result-object `combined`. Specifically, you may want to make adjustments to the `size` and `isCovered` members as well, but follow this pattern and you should be fine. *Neither* operation should require making changes to `A` or `*this`.

Answer (score -1):

Try to change this

```
TrashCan TrashCan::operator+ (TrashCan A)
{
    TrashCan combined;
    combined.my_Contents= my_Contents + A.my_Contents;
}
```

With this

```
TrashCan TrashCan::operator+ (TrashCan A)
{
    this->my_Contents += A.my_Contents;
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: This is not correct. The operator should not need to modify *either* `*this` or `A`. This would be more appropriate for `operator +=` and even there, the return *type* would be a non-const reference.

Comment: Oops my bad. Thumbs up. Edited.

Comment: Edited maybe, but it still isn't correct. `operator +` should return a by-value result of the operation, leaving the operands unchanged. When you write `y = 5; x = y + 7;` you don't expect `y` to suddenly be equivalent to `12`. Neither should that logic apply here.

Comment: Could one of you take a look at my edit and tell me how I would properly implement a subtraction operation? @WhozCraig